# loadOptions is not called when AsyncSelect is wrapped by another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, loadoptions

I have a component that wraps a react-select `AsyncSelect` component:

```
<Wrapper
  id={id}
  values={values}
  loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
/>
```

The wrapper component's `render()` function looks like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <AsyncSelect
      defaultValue={this.props.values}
      placeholder={placeholder || "Select..."}
      cacheOptions
      defaultOptions
      isMulti={true}
      name={this.props.id}
      {...this.props}
    />
  );
}
```

However, `loadOptions` is not being called at all. If I get rid of the wrapper component, and use `AsyncSelect` directly in the parent component, everything is working as expected.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does it work if you explicitly give it?  `loadOptions={this.props.loadOptions}` ?

Comment: No. Not even if I'm passing a function straight to the AsyncSelect component: loadOptions={(inputValue, callback) => {console.log('here!'); callback()}}

Comment: in render before return of wapper please `console.log(this.props.loadOptions)` to see if it's reaching your component.

Comment: Tried it. It passes the function

Comment: It may sound stupid but try doing this `loadOptions={() => this.loadOptions()}`